# How can I close $messages.registerWarning in Tridion 2013 SP1?

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

I tried the following but the warning still appears in the middle of the window:

```
myMsg = $messages.registerWarning("myTitle","myDesc",null, true);

myMsg .doArchive();
myMsg .dispose();
```

Registering a 'question' then archiving works fine (the question disappears).

My code snippet works in Tridion 2013 (no SP)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with your 4th parameter that you are passing to $messages.registerWarning...

```
$messages.registerWarning("myTitle", "myDesc", null, true); // true is for isModal
```

This is essentially making your warning as a modal that requires user interaction, and you wont be able to the `doArchive` and `dispose` on it until after the user has clicked the button.  Setting this option to false will allow it to work just like a notification where the message will appear at the top right of the screen, and will be disposable without having the user to click anything.

```
$messages.registerWarning("title","desc",null, false)
$messages.getActiveMessages().forEach(function (message) {
    message.doArchive();
    message.dispose();
});
```

Hope that helps!